# Get random numbers within one standard deviation

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, random, normal-distribution

I want to generate random numbers, lets say 100. Now I am using numpy for the purpose like:

```
print numpy.random.normal(loc=200,scale=50,size=100)
```

But I want the numbers to be generated only one standard deviation apart from the mean value i.e loc. What would be the best way ?

Should I simply do something like:

```
print numpy.random.randint(150, high=250, size=100)
```

or is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: What do you mean "generated only one standard deviation apart from the mean value"? Do you mean that you want the resulting distribution of numbers to have a standard deviation of 1? In that case, `numpy.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=1.0, ...)`.

Comment: Oh, you want a truncated normal distribution. `numpy.random` does not have that, but `scipy.stats` does. `from scipy import stats; stats.truncnorm.rvs(-1.0, 1.0, loc=200.0, scale=50.0, size=100)`

Comment: May be the question itself is a stupid question as normally distributed data should contains values 0-max with bell shaped curve.

Comment: Well `-inf` to `+inf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pick one number

As suggested in [@Robert Kern's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163633/robert-kern) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643993/get-random-numbers-within-one-standard-deviation#comment45588741_28643993) use scipy's [truncnorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html)

```
from scipy import stats

arr = stats.truncnorm.rvs(-1, 1, loc=200.0, scale=50.0, size=1) 
print(arr[0])
```

The first two parameters indicate the range [a, b] (measured in standard deviations), `loc` is the mean (the center of the distribution), and `scale` is the standard deviation (how spread the distribution is).

## Plot numbers within -1 to +3 STDs

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# -1 to +3 standard deviations apart
r = stats.truncnorm.rvs(-1, 3, loc=200.0, scale=50.0, size=10**6)

plt.hist(r, bins=100, color='blue')
plt.xlabel("value")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
plt.show()
```

[image: -1 to +3 stds]

---

**Sidenote:** `randint()` and `normal()` do **not** pick a number the same way.

[numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

> Return random integers from the “discrete uniform” distribution in the “half-open” interval.

[numpy.random.normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

> Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

The odds of getting any number in the chosen interval using `randint()` is the same, unlike numbers from a [normal distribution](http://killianhma0910.wikispaces.com/file/view/NormalCurve.png/119921461/NormalCurve.png) (odds of getting a number closer to the peak are greater).